Ошибка при создание диаграммы в SQL Server (SSMS)
Пытаюсь соединить таблицу Штат с состовным PK кодОтдела и кодДолжности и таблицу Назначения c PK номер_назначения, но получаю ошибку. Я эти таблицы соединял по кодОтдела и кодДолжности из таблицы Штат и кодОтдела и кодДолжности в таблице Назначения.
'Назначения' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_Назначения_Штат'.  
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Назначения_Штат". The conflict occurred in database "pr", table "dbo.Штат".

Штат:

Назначения:

СКРИПТ ТАБЛИЦЫ Назначения:
USE [pr]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Назначения]    Script Date: 13.05.2024 23:57:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Назначения](
    [номер_назначения] [int] NOT NULL,
    [номер_сотрудника] [int] NOT NULL,
    [датаПриема] [date] NULL,
    [датаУвольнения] [date] NULL,
    [кодДолжности] [int] NULL,
    [кодОтдела] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Назначения] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [номер_назначения] ASC,
    [номер_сотрудника] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Назначения]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Назначения_Должности] FOREIGN KEY([кодДолжности])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Должности] ([кодДолжности])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Назначения] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Назначения_Должности]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Назначения]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Назначения_Отделы] FOREIGN KEY([кодОтдела])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Отделы] ([кодОтдела])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Назначения] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Назначения_Отделы]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Назначения]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Назначения_Сотрудники] FOREIGN KEY([номер_сотрудника])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Сотрудники] ([номер])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Назначения] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Назначения_Сотрудники]
GO

Штат:
USE [pr]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Штат]    Script Date: 13.05.2024 23:58:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Штат](
    [кодОтдела] [int] NOT NULL,
    [кодДолжности] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Кол_во] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Штат] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [кодОтдела] ASC,
    [кодДолжности] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Вот тут пытаюсь связать таблицы:

И получаю ошибку:

Работаю в СУБД: SQL Server Management Studio  20.0.70.0
и используя SQL Server 2017

Во-первых, по скриншотам ничего не видно. Замените их на полные CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц непосредственно перед попыткой создать внешний ключ. Во-вторых, приведите полный текст ALTER TABLE, приводящий к ошибке. В третьих, приведите полный текст сообщения об ошибке, с максимально возможным сохранением форматирования (вот тут скриншот - хорошее дополнение). В четвёртых, укажите точно СУБД и её версию, а также точное наименование и версию используемого клиента.

@Akina обновил данные

Сам код работает нормально (см. https://dbfiddle.uk/KD0xRVMr). Сообщение об ошибке так и вовсе утверждает, что внешний ключ уже имеется... проверяйте действительную структуру таблицы на предмет наличия имени (вообще - проверьте имя по sys.objects), пробуйте другое имя ограничения, пробуйте в конце концов просто создать внешний ключ кодом, а не визуально.

@Akina у меня до этого была таблица Штат я ее удалил что бы создать новую, но в старой таблице штат я удалил составной первичный ключ, думая что удалил и внешний похоже не удалил. А если я через код создам ПК то в диаграмме они будут отображаться?
